# how to get the row number from a table cell button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i am passing a very hard time with js.its take me a day to solve a single problem.i am not understanding when i will pass this hard time.i am just wnats to get a table row number from a table cell button.means think a table have 5 rows which data is fetched from a database.and every row contains a button.if i click a button it will return or show me the row number which this button belongs.
my html and php code----

```
<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Heading</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Body</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Course</th>
</tr>
<?php

mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
    mysql_select_db("db name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql = "sql";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
         echo '<tr>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["pic_path"].'</div></td>             
         <td><div onclick="getval(this)" class="cventablehead" id="ventablehead" style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll; cursor: pointer; color:red;">'.$row["heading"].'</div></td>
         <td>'.$row["adding_date"].'</td>
         <td><div style="width:100%;height: 60px;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll">'.$row["body"].'</div></td>
         <td><button onclick="idna5(this)">Add</button></td>
         </tr>';
    }
?>
  </table>
```

my js code----

```
    function idna5(obj)
    {
       //alert(obj.index());--1st try
       alert($(obj).index());---2nd try
    }
```

[image: table name desire output]

if you guys can please help me

Comment: And the outputs for you js tries are?

Comment: 1st output is nothing and second is always show 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Using a class**:

```js
$(function(){
  $('button.idna5').on('click',function(){
         alert($(this).closest('tr').index())
  })
})
```

```html
<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Heading</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Body</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Course</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button class="idna5">Add</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button class="idna5">Add</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button class="idna5">Add</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> **Calling a function** as you used in your code:

```js
function idna5(el){
 alert($(el).closest('tr').index())
}
```

```html
<table class="w3-table-all w3-margin-top" id="myTable">
<tr>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Picture Path</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Heading</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Adding Date</th>
  <th style="width:22.5%;">Vendor Body</th>
  <th style="width:10%;">Add A Course</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button onclick="idna5(this)">Add</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button onclick="idna5(this)">Add</button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td><button onclick="idna5(this)">Add</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```